# How to get the attribute value in template html with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I wrote a directive but I don't know how to get the attribute of the directive in template html, those attributes are used in ngIf to determine which div elements will be displayed, pls take a look at below code snippet.

directive use:

```
<geo-country-selector type="WGC"></geo-country-selector>
```

template html:

```
<div ng-if="type.indexOf('W')>0">
    ...
</div>
<div ng-if="type.indexOf('G')>0">
    ...
</div>
```

I need to get the attribute type's value in the template html. I did lots of research on that, but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks

The directive can be like Anik said :

```
link : function(scope,element,attr){
    ...

},
scope: {
    type: '@'
}
```

Comment: Show your directive code, are you binding `type` to the directive's scope?

Comment: hello , it has nothing to do with directive maybe, currently I'm not sure if I really need to bind type to the directive's scope, what I want is just to get the value of type in template html easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive add a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) function then add attrs value to scope then you can check condition in your template like that

try like this

```
link : function(scope,element,attr){

    scope.type=attr.type

}
```

There is another way by creating isolate scope like this

```
scope: {
    type: '@'
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, actually I tried this way first, it worked but it's not that convenient cause I had to create variable in scope for every attribute, which means I created attributes twice ,so I posted the question.

Comment: hello @Anik ,  I know how to get the value of attribute in directive , just need to know how to get it in template html.

Comment: did you tried isolate scope that i mentioned in my answer ??

Comment: it works , thanks. Property defined in scope will also exist in $scope, so it's fine to access the property in template.